# Insert rows into SQL Server table from json

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-json

Trying to work up a stored procedure to insert json as rows into an existing empty table. The json properties match the table columns.

This stored procedure returns 3 errors shown below the following code

```
declare @json nvarchar(max)
declare @db_name sysname = 'test1'
set @json= N'{
"Cutouts":
[      
    {
        "ItemCode":"Circle",
        "MinutesLabor":8         
    },
    {
        "ItemCode":"Star",
        "MinutesLabor":10
    }   
]
}';
--print @json
declare @str nvarchar(max)

set @str = N'INSERT [' + QUOTENAME (@db_name) + '].[dbo].[Cutouts] (ItemCode, MinutesLabor)
SELECT ItemCode, MinutesLabor
FROM OPENJSON(' + @json + ')
     WITH (
     ItemCode varchar(8) ''$.Cutouts.ItemCode'', 
     MinutesLabor decimal(9,1) ''$.Cutouts.MinutesLabor''';
--print @str
exec (@str)
```

The errors are

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
> Incorrect syntax near 'Cutouts'.

I've tried to follow the json format used in an example of working with json in sql server at [SQLShack](https://www.sqlshack.com/the-json_query-function-to-extract-objects-from-json-data/). I've validated the json at [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)

> The identifier that starts with '         {       "ItemCode":"Circle",
> "MinutesLabor":8       ' is too long. Maximum length is 128.

I've tried starting the sp with `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` and `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` and the same error is thrown in each case

The third error is

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
>
> The previous statement does end in a semi-colon

There are many examples showing how to insert json into SQL Server and I've tried to follow as best I can, but the scenarios all seem more complex than mine and yet I still can't get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few formatting issues.

Firstly when you are concatenating your json with your Sql string, it needs to be quoted; You need a closing bracket at the end and you can define the json path in the OpenJson element. The following works:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max)
declare @db_name sysname = 'test1'
set @json= N'''{
"Cutouts":
[      
    {
        "ItemCode":"Circle",
        "MinutesLabor":8         
    },
    {
        "ItemCode":"Star",
        "MinutesLabor":10
    }   
]
}'',''$.Cutouts''';
--print @json
declare @str nvarchar(max)

set @str = N'INSERT [' + QUOTENAME (@db_name) + '].[dbo].[Cutouts] (ItemCode, MinutesLabor)
SELECT ItemCode, MinutesLabor
FROM OPENJSON(' + @json + ')
     WITH (
     ItemCode varchar(8) ''$.ItemCode'', 
     MinutesLabor decimal(9,1) ''$.MinutesLabor'')';
--print @str
exec (@str)
```

See [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=378cc519d1b0bddbec4cb3a6fd9a1fc7)

Comment: You need to parameterize `@json` properly via `sp_executesql`, and `QUOTENAME` doesn't need the extra brackets around it

Answer (score 2):

First off, you only need dynamic SQL here if your database name is dynamic

Assuming that is the case, then the correct way to do this is to pass `@json` as a parameter into the dynamic SQL, via `sp_executesql`. Note also, that if you use `QUOTENAME` then the database name should not be in brackets.

```sql
declare @json nvarchar(max);
declare @db_name sysname = 'test1';
set @json= N'{
"Cutouts":
[      
    {
        "ItemCode":"Circle",
        "MinutesLabor":8         
    },
    {
        "ItemCode":"Star",
        "MinutesLabor":10
    }   
]
}'
--print @json
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
INSERT ' + QUOTENAME(@db_name) + '.[dbo].[Cutouts] (ItemCode, MinutesLabor)
SELECT ItemCode, MinutesLabor
FROM OPENJSON(@json, ''$.Cutouts'')
     WITH (
     ItemCode varchar(8) ''$.ItemCode'', 
     MinutesLabor decimal(9,1) ''$.MinutesLabor'')';

--print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
  N'@json nvarchar(max)',
  @json = @json;
```

If you are on SQL Server 2017+ you can also parameterize the JSON path expression.